# does launch coroutine builder cause suspend functions to run on new thread?

Tags: android, multithreading, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-android-extensions

Started using Kotlin coroutines recently

here is the syntax:

```
main(){
    launch(Dispatchers.Main){
        delay(2000)
        print("inside coroutine")
    }
    print("outside coroutine")
}
```

I understand that outside coroutine is printed first and then inside coroutine is printed because delay is a suspend function and it blocks the coroutine only and not the thread itself.

But as the coroutine would need to be executed somewhere else(like on a different thread) for it to know when to resume, how is this taken care of?

It can be any process intense suspend function instead of delay.

Only thing I can't understand is Does the suspend function actually run on a different thread under the hood irrespective of the Dispatcher provided in launch{} builder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`suspend` functions are designed to block current coroutine, not the thread, it means they should run in background thread. For example [`delay`](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/delay.html) function blocks coroutine for a given time without blocking a thread and resumes it after a specified time. You can create a `suspend` function which runs on background thread like the following:

```
suspend fun someSuspendFun() = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
    // do some long running operation
}
```

Using `withContext(Dispatchers.IO)` we switch the context of function execution to background thread. [`withContext`](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/with-context.html) function also can return some result.

To call that function we can use a coroutine builder:

```
someScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main){
    someSuspendFun() // suspends current coroutine without blocking the Main Thread
    print("inside coroutine") // this line will be executed in the Main Thread after `someSuspendFun()` function finish execution.
}
```

Comment: So you mean to say only when the thread is free after executing all the statements, then only the coroutine which is run on main thread is resumed?

Comment: I added some explanation to the answer, please check.

Answer (score 0):

delay() function is run asynchronously under the hood. Other suspend functions would block the thread if run using Dispatchers.Main

Comment: Suspend functions that block should never be run on Dispatchers.Main or Dispatchers.Default. The compiler will give you a warning if you do. The convention for any blocking suspend function is to wrap it in `withContext(Dispatchers.IO)` so it can safely be called from any place in any coroutine.

Comment: `Other suspend functions would block the thread if run using Dispatchers.Main` that's not how things work, if it is suspending task why would it block the thread? All the suspend function calls run asynchronously behind the hood using the current Continuation as the resume callback.

Comment: I am using latest kotlin compiler plugin and I don't see any warning is issued when running suspend function on main thread. @Tenfour04

Comment: The compiler can't identify all blocking methods. I think it mostly just looks for Java methods that throw IOExceptions and uses that as a rule of thumb. But also Thread.sleep(). If you put `Thread.sleep()` in a coroutine with `Dispatchers.Main` or `Dispatchers.Default`, it will give you a warning. It doesn't stop you from doing it though. But the point is, your statement, "Other suspend functions would block the thread if run using Dispatchers.Main` is only true if you are incorrectly composing these other suspend functions.

Comment: It will never give you a warning for calling a `suspend` function on Dispatcher.Main, because suspend functions never should block. The warning would be in the incorrectly composed suspend function.

Comment: yes, I meant calling the suspend function explicitly using Dispatchers.Main. so as per the info I received here, I guess I must have rephrased my OP. Once the thread is free after executing all the statements outside of the coroutine launched using launch{}, then the coroutine is resumed on whichever thread(be it main or io) it is called right? @Tenfour04

Comment: That's only true of single thread dispatchers like `Dispatchers.Main`. If you are using `Dispatchers.IO`, each time the coroutine resumes, it could be on a different Thread. The reason launching a coroutine on `Dispatchers.Main` from the main thread doesn't result in it immediately starting is that the coroutine is queued up to run on the Main thread and must wait for the Android Looper to send it all the jobs that have been posted to the main thread.